# How find only the newly added/created files when comparing two folders?

Tags: java, android, bash, shell, sh

I have 2 folders where one is an initial copy from the other one and I want to check the newly added/created files in the original folder every N seconds (I do the timer in Java), so I am using `diff -r original_dir copy_dir`. 
The problem was that `diff` detects and returns other changes too like the changes in files so it is difficult to wrap the output in Java for each case. 
So how can I only list the different files only using `diff` and ignore the changes in their content/date/size?

Comment: -q, --brief  report only when files differ

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/ls -c1 original_dir >original_list.txt
/bin/ls -c1 copy_dir >copy_list.txt

diff original_list.txt copy_list.txt
```

This will list all new files from the copy directory.